# How to use convolution function in cntk?

Tags: convolution, cntk

I'm trying to convolve two constant arrays using `cntk.convolution` function.

This is my code:

```
import cntk as C

w = C.constant(1, (2, 2))
a = C.constant(2, (2, 2))

c = C.convolution(w, a)

print(c.eval())
```

But it leads to the following error

> RuntimeError: Convolution currently requires the main operand to have dynamic axes

How should I use `convolution` function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this example in docstring of convolution method.

```
img = np.reshape(np.arange(25.0, dtype=np.float32), (1, 5, 5))
x = C.input_variable(img.shape)
filter = np.reshape(np.array([2, -1, -1, 2], dtype=np.float32), (1, 2, 2))
kernel = C.constant(value=filter)
out = np.round(C.convolution(kernel, x, auto_padding=[False]).eval({x: [img]}), 5)
print(out)
```